# Sorting a list of random transactions using dplyr

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr

Assume the following set of original transactions:

```
library(tidyverse)

original_transactions <- data.frame(
  row = 1:6,
  start = 0,
  change = runif(6, min = -10, max = 10) %>% round(2),
  end = 0
) %>% mutate(
  temp = cumsum(change),
  end = 100 + temp, # End balance
  start = end - change # Start balance
) %>% select(
  -temp
)
```

[image]

It shows a (chronological) sequence of transactions with a starting balance of $100.00 and an ending balance of $95.65, with six transactions/changes.

Now assume that you receive a jumbled version of this

```
transactions <- original_transactions %>% sample_n(
  6
) %>% mutate(
  row = row_number() # Original sequence is unknown
)
```

[image]

How can I reverse-engineer the sequence in R? That is, to get the sort order of `transactions` to match that of `original_transactions`? Ideally I'd like to do this using `dplyr` and a sequence of pipes `%>%` and avoid loops.

Assume that the start/end balances will be unique and that, in general, the number of transactions can vary.

Comment: Is your question assuming you dont have access to original_transactions? Do you have any unique data, like a timestamp? or are there any rules about how the data is jumbled?

Comment: I doubt if this is possible to do this without `for` loop. I would be curious to know if it is.

Comment: @Rilcon42: I don't have access to `original_transactions`, just the jumbled selection of transactions without timestamps. `original_transactions` is just for reference.

Comment: Please use `set.seed()` to ensure reproducibility when you use functions like `runif`

Comment: You could use a series of `left_join`s and then `gather` with this example. Generalising that so it worked with any number  of transactions would be hard. A `for` loop is the obvious solution

Comment: I assume that your original data file is much longer. If you have the value 100 more than once in start, you will get great difficulties. What is the variable row good for if its values are random?

Answer (score 6):

First, let

```
original_transactions
#   row  start change    end
# 1   1 100.00   2.33 102.33
# 2   2 102.33  -6.52  95.81
# 3   3  95.81  -4.20  91.61
# 4   4  91.61  -3.56  88.05
# 5   5  88.05   7.92  95.97
# 6   6  95.97   3.61  99.58

transactions
#   row  start change    end
# 1   1 100.00   2.33 102.33
# 2   2  91.61  -3.56  88.05
# 3   3  95.81  -4.20  91.61
# 4   4 102.33  -6.52  95.81
# 5   5  88.05   7.92  95.97
# 6   6  95.97   3.61  99.58
```

and

```
diffs <- outer(transactions$start, transactions$start, `-`)
matches <- abs(sweep(diffs, 2, transactions$change, `-`)) < 1e-3
```

I guess that computing `diffs` is the most computationally expensive part in the whole solution. `diffs` has all possible differences between `start` of your `transactions`. Then comparing those with the `change` column in `matches` we know which pairs of rows of `transactions` should go together. If there were no problems regarding numeric precision, we could then use the `match` function and be done quickly. In this case, however, we have the following **two options**.

---

First, we may use `igraph`.

```
library(igraph)
(g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(t(matches) * 1))
# IGRAPH 45d33f0 D--- 6 5 -- 
# + edges from 45d33f0:
# [1] 1->4 2->5 3->2 4->3 5->6
```

That is, we have a hidden path graph: 1->4->3->2->5->6 which we want to recover. It is given by the longest path from the vertex which has no incoming edges (which is `1`):

```
transactions[as.vector(tail(all_simple_paths(g, from = which(rowSums(matches) == 0)), 1)[[1]]), ]
#   row  start change    end
# 1   1 100.00   2.33 102.33
# 4   4 102.33  -6.52  95.81
# 3   3  95.81  -4.20  91.61
# 2   2  91.61  -3.56  88.05
# 5   5  88.05   7.92  95.97
# 6   6  95.97   3.61  99.58
```

---

Another option is recursive.

```
fun <- function(x, path = x) {
  if(length(xNew <- which(matches[, x])) > 0)
    fun(xNew, c(path, xNew))
  else path
}
transactions[fun(which(rowSums(matches) == 0)), ]
#   row  start change    end
# 1   1 100.00   2.33 102.33
# 4   4 102.33  -6.52  95.81
# 3   3  95.81  -4.20  91.61
# 2   2  91.61  -3.56  88.05
# 5   5  88.05   7.92  95.97
# 6   6  95.97   3.61  99.58
```

It uses the same unique longest path graph idea as the previous approach.

---

No explicit loops... And of course you may rewrite everything with `%>%`, but it won't be as pretty as you want; this is not really a traditional data transformation task where `dplyr` is best.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using a `tidyverse` pipeline. It matches `start` and `end` figures (using character to avoid floating point problems), then uses `purrr::accumulate` to construct the chain, and `slice` to reorder the rows...

```
library(tidyverse)
orig <- transactions %>% 
  mutate(ind = match(as.character(start), as.character(end))) %>% #indicator variable
  slice(accumulate(1:n(),                #do it (no of rows) times
                   ~match(., ind),       #work along chain of matches
                   .init = NA)) %>%      #start with the one with no matching end value
  select(-ind)                           #remove ind variable

transactions
  row  start change    end
1   1 111.34   9.12 120.46
2   2 100.00  -0.18  99.82
3   3 125.29  -9.09 116.20
4   4  99.82   8.33 108.15
5   5 120.46   4.83 125.29
6   6 108.15   3.19 111.34

orig
  row  start change    end
1   2 100.00  -0.18  99.82
2   4  99.82   8.33 108.15
3   6 108.15   3.19 111.34
4   1 111.34   9.12 120.46
5   5 120.46   4.83 125.29
6   3 125.29  -9.09 116.20
```

Answer (score 0):

The following minimal example provides `sort_transactions` - a recursive function that sequentially identifies pairs of starting and ending balances using a series of joins.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123456) # For reproducibility with runif()

# A set of original transactions
original_transactions <- data.frame(
  row = 1:6,
  start = 0,
  change = runif(6, min = -10, max = 10) %>% round(2),
  end = 0
) %>% mutate(
  temp = cumsum(change),
  end = 100 + temp,
  start = end - change
) %>% select(
  -temp
)

# Jumble original_transactions
transactions <- original_transactions %>% sample_n(
  6
) %>% mutate(
  row = row_number()
)

sort_transactions <- function(input_df) {

  if (nrow(input_df) < 2) {
    return (input_df)
  } else { # nrow(input_df) >= 2
    return (
      input_df %>% anti_join(
        input_df,
        by = c(
          'start' = 'end'
        )
      ) %>% bind_rows(
        sort_transactions(
          input_df %>% semi_join(
            input_df,
            by = c(
              'start' = 'end'
            )
          ) %>% semi_join(
            input_df,
            by = c(
              'end' = 'start'
            )
          )
        ),
        input_df %>% anti_join(
          input_df,
          by = c(
            'end' = 'start'
          )
        )
      )
    )
  }

}
```

Usage (requires [conversion of numeric columns to character for comparison](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4046)):

```
transactions %>% mutate(
  start = start %>% as.character(),
  end = end %>% as.character()
) %>% sort_transactions() %>% mutate(
  start = start %>% as.numeric(),
  end = end %>% as.numeric()
)
# row  start change    end
#   2 100.00   5.96 105.96
#   5 105.96   5.07 111.03
#   6 111.03  -2.17 108.86
#   1 108.86  -3.17 105.69
#   4 105.69  -2.77 102.92
#   3 102.92  -6.03  96.89
```